# detect phone locale

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I would like my app by default use the **phone locale** for localization.

But how can I detect the locale of the phone ? Anyone can hint me on this?

(I have created `/res/values/string.xml`, and I know I can create other locale resource like: `res/values-fr/strings.xml`)

Comment: try this :`Locale myPhoneLocale = Locale.getDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have provided the same local resources as your phone is on, then it will automatically pick those resources. So you don't need to worry about it.

Otherwise `Locale.getDefault();` will provide you the phone's current locale.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
 Locale.getDefault()
```